# Allow Rest API to respond only to a specific server

Tags: api, rest, security

I have a simple REST api endpoint, which will respond to the requests from out side. Now I want to secure it. I only want my end point to respond to requests which comes from my server (host).

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Can we trust HTTP_REFERER?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you referring to requests made from a client on a page on your server, or a request that actually originates from the server itself (eg via `curl`)

Comment: You can deny/allow IP's using `.htaccess`

Comment: `CORS` settings on your server can allow only specific host to request that resource. Basic authentication can also be a option. you can make a virtual host on your server and bind it your local IP.

Comment: Actually, I am presenting Client a wizard. basically from step to step I am updating my db based on API calls. I want those API calls only made from my server. 

Meaning, if some one send the same API call from another server, I want my API not to answer that request.

Comment: @CollinD, I am referring a request made from a Client on a page on my server, YES.

Answer (score 0):

You can deny/allow IP's using `.htaccess`

```
<files api.php>
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
   allow from 0.0.0.0 # Your Server IP
   allow from 0.0.0.0 # Your Client IP
   allow from 0.0.0.0 # Your Clients another IP
</files>
```

Hope this help

Comment: When a Client do a request do we get the server IP or there machine IP in the request? When I put my server IP, will this work?

Comment: Yes when a Client do a request we will get the client IP. To allow multiple IPs just add `allow from 0.0.0.0 # Your Client IP` line in the above code.

Comment: But im my case, I dont know my Client IP. I am bit new to this. Could you please give me some more idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we trust HTTP_REFERER

No. Referrer is sent by client so can be anything and cannot be trusted. You can however try checking `REMOTE_ADDR` against allowed IP's or if you do not assign IPs per user, you can simply set up firewall using i.e. iptables, use `.htaccess` with proper `Allow/Deny` entries or any other software that controls the traffic before it reach your API. This will allow you to decouple this feature from main API

Comment: Thanks for the response. When controlling traffic can be allow it to answer my client requests only when the client made it using my server. Meaning, if the client send a same API request from another server, can I block it. Because I dont have IPs of each and every Client. Please help!

Comment: I do not know your API but if you got something like login in it, then record IP at that moment and you can then check against it later on